# how to pass the inline edited td value to database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i am making the html table with an inline edit using javascript when the table td edited using inline edit i want to save the edited value in database i don't know how to pass the edited value to database and save,please any one guide me how  to do this thanks.

My java script

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload=function(){
$("table td").click( function( e ){

    if ( $(this).find('input').length ) {
         return ;   
    }        
    var input = $("<input type='text' size='5' />")
                      .val( $(this).text() );

    $(this).empty().append( input );

    $(this).find('input')
           .focus()
           .blur( function( e ){
                  $(this).parent('td').text( 
                     $(this).val()
                  );
            });               

});  

</script>
```

Html

```
 <html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> edit</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
$dbHost = 'localhost'; // usually localhost
$dbUsername = 'fms';
$dbPassword = 'xxxxx';
$dbDatabase = 'fms';
$db = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) or die ("Unable to connect to Database Server.");
mysql_select_db ($dbDatabase, $db) or die ("Could not select database.");     
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM supplierprice");       
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Region</th>
<th>Country</th>
<th>Network Name</th>
<th>Mcc</th>
<th>Mnc</th>
<th>Mnp</th>        
</tr>";    
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['region'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['country'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['networkname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['mcc'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['mnc'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['mnp'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";       
?>      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable, dont reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple ways to accomplish your task. I would say use ajax call on your click function and pass that data to a new page that have query for update data in table.

here are details about using ajax call.

[Basics about ajax calls](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: but here i am using javascript

Comment: javascript or jquery its one and same thing u jst need to make ajax call that will transfer the control to your page that have update query written and pass your value along with ajax call.